# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am programming an Android app and on two devices my app crashes with the following Problem:

Update: There seems to be a problem, which was about the mediarecorder. Now I get a slightly different problem:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: online.simpledesign.bikelog, PID: 14660
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:203)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:117)
    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:123)
    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:168)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:46)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:97)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:980)
    at online.simpledesign.bikelog.Record$MediaPrepareTask.doInBackground(Record.java:539)
    at online.simpledesign.bikelog.Record$MediaPrepareTask.doInBackground(Record.java:524)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 4 more
```

The Code that is executed when the error occurs is:

```
class MediaPrepareTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // initialize video camera
        if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
            // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
            // now you can start recording

            mMediaRecorder.start();

        } else {
            // prepare didn't work, release the camera
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            //Rückmeldung: Kamera konnte nicht gestartet werden
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Record.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Achtung");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Kamera konnte nicht gestartet werden. Du kannst trotzdem die Daten aufzeichnen und mir so helfen.");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Okay",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (!result) {
            Record.this.finish();
        }

    }


}
```

I tried every solution here but non of them worked. Even more confusing for me is that on some devices it works without a problem.
Xperia XZ1 Compact with Android 8.0 and Google Pixel with Android 7.1 throw that problem.

Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: Here is what happens in prepareVideoRecorder:

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (configure_preview)
        mCamera = CameraHelper.getDefaultCameraInstance();
        if(CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(0,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA)){

            // We need to make sure that our preview and recording video size are supported by the
            // camera. Query camera to find all the sizes and choose the optimal size given the
            // dimensions of our preview surface.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            List<Camera.Size> mSupportedVideoSizes = parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
            Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalVideoSize(mSupportedVideoSizes, mSupportedPreviewSizes, mPreview.getWidth(), mPreview.getHeight());

            // Use the same size for recording profile.
            CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA);
            profile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width;
            profile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height;

            // likewise for the camera object itself.
            parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            try {
                // Requires API level 11+, For backward compatibility use {@link setPreviewDisplay}
                // with {@link SurfaceView}
                mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mPreview.getSurfaceTexture());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Surface texture is unavailable or unsuitable" + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
            // END_INCLUDE (configure_preview)


            // BEGIN_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
            mCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

            // Step 2: Set sources
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
            // Step 4: Set output file
            mOutputFile = CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
            if (mOutputFile == null) {
                return false;
            }
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFile.getPath());
            // END_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)

            // Step 5: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
            try {
                mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's in your prepareVideoRecorder method?

Comment: I updated the inital question :-)

Comment: That's a completely different problem then what you'd originally posted. You cannot show a `Dialog` directly from `doInBackground()`. Just move it to `onPostExecute()`, since you don't really need to show it there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `prepareVideoRecorder()`, you should check first whether the profile you want to use, is supported or not -

```
if(CamcorderProfile.hasProfile()){
 // then get profile ....
}
```

> public static boolean hasProfile (int cameraId,
>                   int quality);

If it does not support then you will always get the crash because the profile is not supported on that device. So you need to check first and if supported only then perform rest of the operations.

Comment: I updated the inital question - adding the hasProfile did not change anything. Thanks anyway!